# ARM Template - Azure SQL Database Diagnostics & Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: database, azure-sql, diagnostic, azure-arm-template, log-analytics-workspace

Using an **ARM Template** I want to **enable diagnostics settings** for my **Azure SQL Database** and have that data stored in a **Log Analytics workspace** I created. I want to enable the errors, timeouts, blocks and wait statistics logs and the basic metric option. I was able to get this working with a web app so I took a similar approach but my template fails and throws errors saying the metrics or diagnostic categories I reference **don't exist** or **not supported**. Here's some of the resources section my **template**:

I'm not sure if **additional settings need to be enabled or referenced in the template** for this to work but I would appreciate any help, thanks!

```
          "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "databases",
                    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
                    "name": "[parameters('sqlDatabase')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "tags": {},
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('sqlServer')]"
                    ],
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "GP_Gen5_4",
                        "tier": "GeneralPurpose"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                    }
                },

                {
                    "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
                    "name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('diagnostics-name'))]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServer'))]",
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('sqlServer'), parameters('sqlDatabase'))]"
                    ],

                    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "[parameters('diagnostics-name')]",
                        "workspaceId": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('loganalytics-rg'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspacename'))]",
                        "logs": [
                            {
                                "category": "Errors",
                                "enabled": "true",
                                "retentionPolicy": {
                                    "enabled": "true",
                                    "days": 7
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "category": "DatabaseWaitStatistics",
                                "enabled": "true",
                                "retentionPolicy": {
                                    "enabled": "true",
                                    "days": 7
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "category": "Timeouts",
                                "enabled": "true",
                                "retentionPolicy": {
                                    "enabled": "true",
                                    "days": 7
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "category": "Blocks",
                                "enabled": "true",
                                "retentionPolicy": {
                                    "enabled": "true",
                                    "days": 7
                                }
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the changes below to my ARM template I was able to deploy an azure sql server and database with diagnostics enabled on the DB which directs the diagnostic logs to an existing Log Analytics workspace:

```
"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('sqlServer')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('adminLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                "version": "12.0"
            },

            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "databases",
                    "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
                    "name": "[parameters('sqlDatabase')]",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "tags": {},
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('sqlServer')]"
                    ],
                    "sku": {
                        "name": "GP_Gen5_4",
                        "tier": "GeneralPurpose"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                    }
                },

                {
                    "type": "microsoft.sql/servers/databases/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('sqlServer'),'/',parameters('sqlDatabase'),'/microsoft.insights/', parameters('diagnostics-name'))]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[parameters('sqlServer')]",
                        "[parameters('sqlDatabase')]"
                    ],

                    "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
                    "properties": {
                        
                        "workspaceId": "[concat('subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',parameters('loganalytics-rg'),'/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/',parameters('workspacename'))]",
                        "logs": [
                            {
                                "category": "Errors",
                                "enabled": true
                            },

                            {
                                "category": "Timeouts",
                                "enabled": true
                            },

                            {
                                "category": "Blocks",
                                "enabled": true
                            },

                            {
                                "category": "Deadlocks",
                                "enabled": true
                            },

                            {
                                "category": "SQLInsights",
                                "enabled": true
                            },

                            {
                                "category": "DatabaseWaitStatistics",
                                "enabled": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "metrics":[
                            {
                                "category": "Basic",
                                "enabled": true
                            },
                            {
                                "category": "InstanceAndAppAdvanced",
                                "enabled": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this setting isn't being exported into the ARM template if one sets it up manually beforehand? I have an existing database which is configured to send logs to an existing log analytics workspace, but when I click export template, it's not being included.

Comment: No idea, I've had little to no luck trying to use the ARM templates that are generated for existing resources. I've always had to do a lot of reconfiguration to get them to work. I found its easier to just start from scratch. Not the answer you're looking for but that's been the case for me.